# Program to work out percentages from a group

Tags: c#, math

Can someone help me with some coding. I want to work out what the final percentage of this grouping

```
100% of 4
0% of 1
100% of 12
100% of 2
```

So an answer would be along the lines of

```
95% of 19
```

or something like that.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Surely, this is possible. However, for us to answer this, you need to specify the format in which the data is stored. BTW: What have you tried? Because the math is trivial.

Comment: Currently this is a maths question and has nothing to do with programming because of the reasons Daniel notes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Daniel, What do you mean by the format of the data? I haven't tried much as i'm not sure how to go about solving it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general the formula to compute a "weighted average" of `x% of y` would be:

```
sum(x/100 * y) / sum(y)
```

so your example would yield

```
(1.0 * 4) + (0.0 * 1) + (1.0 * 12) + (1.0 * 2) / (4 + 1 + 12 + 2)

= 18 / 19 = ~94.7%
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have some kind of structure that holds your percentages and the number of items that belong to those percentages, the following code would do what you're asking for:

```
struct Data
{
    double Percent;
    int Count;
}

...

List<Data> items = new List<Data> ();
... // fill your list with Data instances, initialized with values

double total = 0; // running total
int totalcount = 0; // total number of items

for ( int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++ )
{
    totalcount += items[i].Count;
    total += ( items[i].Count * items[i].Percent );
}

double result = total / totalcount;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I went with @Stanley